# Chrome issue "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Any idea? Thank you

Without modifying my code, chrome has suddenly started not executing my page and throws the following problem:

***Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved updating Chrome (I disabled the automatic updates)